# How to I force my Ventura-running Mac to disconnect from wifi when sleeping?

Tags: wifi, sleep-wake, ventura, screen-lock, find-my-mac

Since updating to Ventura, my Mac is forced to stay connected to wifi (likely Bluetooth, or other operating features) when I go to Sleep (now called Locked Screen). I'm sure this is for "Find My" services or other location-tracking services. I did not consent to this and need my computer to sleep. Aside from any ethical issues with this at the very least, it will drain my precious battery.

I appreciate any terminal commands or approaches to automating this task.

Comment: What model of Mac do you have?

Answer (score 4):

**Sleep** and **Lock Screen** are two different things. A Lock screen is simply that: the screen is locked, but all processes continue. Sleep is a low-power mode, where most processes are halted.

There are no "ethical issues". Apple doesn't track your location. You may, if you choose, track the location of your own devices, using **Find My**, which you can always turn off.

In **System Settings**, go to your Apple ID, and select your Mac under "Devices".  You'll then see a switch to turn off Find My Mac.

Find My Mac does not 'drain your precious battery': it consumes very little resources while sleeping, and is the default condition for millions of Macs, whose batteries are largely unaffected.

There have not been any significant changes in Ventura in this area.

Comment: If you have Ventura, you will see that "sleep" is no longer a term used. Instead, some of the "Sleep" settings have been moved to a section called "lock screen".  Apple most certainly does track your location through "find my" services. Whether they do anything with that data is the question. While I have turned off "find my" services, the default is for the computer to maintain its wifi connection without my consent or ability to turn it off. So yes, it is unethical and a huge pain in my ass. Wifi uses battery and I do not consent to participate and give resources to a global mesh network.

Answer (score 0):

Settings of Sleep mode for laptops are in System Settings > Battery.

On right pane at the bottom click "Options". In opening window set "Enable Power Nap" to "Never". This should prevent Mac in sleeping state periodically check for new email, calendar, and other iCloud updates.

There is also "Wake for network access" which could be set as "Never" (other options are "Only of power adapter", "Always").

Refer to Apple Support document [Set sleep and wake settings for your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchle41a6ccd/mac) for more detailed information

Answer (score 0):

Spoke with a Mac specialist who confirmed that this is a new implementation for "Find My" services and cannot be turned off currently. Even with "Find My" services (and all Location Services) turned off, and all sleep network settings set to "never", wifi will remain engaged.

I found my own workaround. I used an app called Power Manager to set a schedule to run a command on sleep and on waking to turn off/on wifi. Seems to work pretty well, however, the app has an incredibly expensive subscription. I will probably have to find an alternative.

I have been a Mac enthusiast for 15 years and I have never seen such an exploitative feature that the owner can not control. Forcing everyone's computers into a giant mesh network is problematic.

Comment: To me, "unethical" requires malicious intent.  For this, I would prefer the term "short-sighted."